# order by issue for column having character and number in same column

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

I have a column in my table having both type of values character and number.I want to display number in ascending order than character in descending order.I tried to use below:

```
order by case when substr(employe_info,1,1) between '0' and '9' then 1 else 2 end,
employe_info
```

But its makes both number and character in same order(asc or desc).

Please assist

```
table name: test_1
columns : id number(10) , 
          employe_info (varchar 50)
```

data:

```
id     employe_info
1      123
2      x
3      y
4      z
5      678
6      265
8      a
9      1020
```

desired output:

```
id   employe_info
1    123
6    265
5    678
9    1020
4    z
3    y
2    x
8    a
```

Comment: give us a sample about your table !

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, but in general you should store numbers in a numeric column and text in a text column.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with updates rather than adding stuff in the comments.

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to achieve such `ordering` when you wanted Output order in a specific position,but you can use a `decode` and achieve this as below:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM test1
ORDER BY DECODE (SUBSTR (employe_info, 1, 1),
                 '0', 1,
                 '1', 1,
                 '2', 1,
                 '3', 1,
                 '4', 1,
                 '5', 1,
                 '6', 1,
                 '7', 1,
                 '8', 1,
                 '9', 1,
                 'z', 2,
                 'y', 3,
                 'x', 4,
                  --Add here more alphabet as per your desired position
                 5);
```

Note: This solultion is as per the data set provided. Incase you add more data then you need to `extend` the position of the `alphabet` in the decode.